# Approximation of irrational numbers.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

I am trying to prove the following claim

> For given $\varepsilon>0$, we can always find an integer $\tau$ such
>   that $\tau\sqrt{2}$ differs from another integer by less than
>   $\varepsilon$ and furthermore it can be proved that there exist
>   infinitely many such numbers $\tau$, and that the difference between
>   two consecutive ones is bounded. Find a bound like this.

---

> Approximation is easy. The main point here is I want to control the
>   distance between two consecutive ones.

I was trying to use the Dirichlet approximation theorem but I couldn't control the distance between two consecutive ones. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I tried already, but still don't know how to control the distance between two consecutive ones. The main point here is not approximation, but I want to control the distance between two consecutive ones.

Comment: We have a sequence of p/q approaches x, but how to bound the distance between two consecutive denominators? Can you say more about that?

Comment: if you mean that for $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ such that $|x_1 \sqrt{2} -y_1| \leq \epsilon$ and  $|x_2 \sqrt{2} -y_2| \leq \epsilon$  then $y_2 \approx (1+\sqrt{2}) y_1$ so you can easily say that $y_2 < 3 y_1$.

Comment: I want to bound $|x_1-x_2|$, not $|y_1-y_2|$.

Comment: its the same so $x_2 \approx (1+\sqrt{2})x_1$ so $x_2 < 3 x_1$

Comment: Then what is a universal constant constant $T = |x_1-x_2|$ ?

Comment: @ Peter: I think you misunderstood my question. I want to find the universal bound $T$ such that in $T$ consecutive integer you can find an integer $m$ such that there exists another integer $n$ so that $|m\sqrt{2} - n| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: You are right, I will delete my comments ...

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\tau \sqrt2$ is within $\epsilon$ of an integer, say that it is $n + \delta$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ and $0 < \delta < \epsilon$. (The corresponding case $n - \delta$ is more or less the same.)

Then consider the sequence $$\tau \sqrt2, 2\tau \sqrt2, 3\tau\sqrt2, \dots.$$

Initially, the fractional parts of the numbers in this sequence go up in steps of $\delta$, but after $k \approx \frac1\delta$ steps, you get to a number $k \tau \sqrt2 = kn + k\delta$ whose fractional part $k\delta$ has gotten very close to $1$; one more step and it will overflow. This means that in particular, $k \tau \sqrt2$ is within $\epsilon$ of the integer $kn+1$.

This will continue happening at intervals of approximately $\frac1\delta$. The fractional parts of this sequence increase by $\delta$ at every step, and every time they pass $1$, the corresponding element of the sequence is with $\epsilon$ of an integer.

(Since the multiples of $\tau \sqrt2$ go up in steps of approximately $\frac1\delta$, the multiples of $\sqrt2$ go up in steps of approximately $\frac{\tau}{\delta}$. We are probably skipping lots of good approximations of $\sqrt2$, of course, but this is good enough for your purposes.)

---

An example. For $\epsilon = 0.1$, we might start with $5 \sqrt2 \approx 7.071$, so that $\delta = 5\sqrt2 - 7 \approx 0.071$.

Then the sequence $$5 \sqrt2, 10\sqrt2, 15\sqrt2, 20\sqrt2, \dots$$ will be approximately $$7.071, 14.142, 21.213, 28.284, \dots$$ with fractional parts going up by about $0.071$.

Eventually these fractional parts get close to $1$. Since $\frac1\delta \approx 14.071$, after $14$ steps we get to $70 \sqrt 2 \approx 98.995$, and after $15$ steps we get to $75 \sqrt2 \approx 106.066$. Both of these are guaranteed to be within $\epsilon$ of an integer, because $|99 - 70\sqrt2| \approx 0.005$ and $|106 - 75\sqrt2| \approx 0.066$ add up to exactly $\delta$.

This will happen every at-most-$15$ multiples of $5\sqrt2$, or every at-most-$75$ multiples of $\sqrt2$.

Comment: But it does gives a ratio bound ,namely $\frac{1}{\delta}$ so ... , the OP is asking about $x_2-x_1 <T$ rather than $\frac{x_2}{x_1} <T$

Comment: @Ahmad $\frac\tau\delta$ is not a bound on the ratio between two adjacent values but a bound on the difference. I've added an example to help make this clear.

Comment: Also, writing the example helped make one weird property of the problem clear to me: the interval between approximations depends not only on $\epsilon$ but also (in a nontrivial way) on properties of $\sqrt2$. If $\frac1\delta$ happens to be really small, then these good approximations are very far apart. This is an inherent property of the problem: if instead of $\sqrt2$ we took a number like $1.000013852...$, we'd see really large gaps between multiples of it that are even within $0.1$ of an integer.

Comment: Can you explain more about the part "This will continue happening at intervals of approximately $\frac{1}{\delta}$?

Comment: I think after the first period, you got an approximation with less than $\delta$, then the next step when you take $\frac{1}{\delta}$ it will be bigger so it is not clear that you have an universal bound.

Comment: @Sean Since the fractional part of the number goes up by steps of $\delta$, it will keep landing in the interval $[0, \frac1\delta]$ every $\frac1\delta$ steps or so: the interval is too big to get skipped. There are either $\lfloor \frac1\delta\rfloor$ or $\lceil \frac1\delta \rceil$ steps between any two times this happens.

Comment: I got it now! Thanks!